# Linux PCIe device driver read/write functions not working for certain addresses

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I have written a PCIe device driver and the read/write functions are not working correctly. The device has 3 memory regions which begin at 0x10800000, 0x0c000000, and 0x80000000. Just for testing purposes, my read and write functions in the driver print out the address passed and return. If I call pread() or pwrite() from a user space app, I see the address passed for the first 2 memory regions, but if I make the call for the third memory region, I see nothing at all as if it didn't even enter the driver read or write functions.

My driver works completely fine on a 64-bit machine running linux version 2.6.32. This other machine that it doesn't work on is a 32-bit machine running linux version 2.6.25. My thought is that maybe 32-bit doesn't like the 0x80000000 address, but I don't know how to verify that or how to fix it if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty vague question (what file are you doing pread/pwrite on?) but since you say everything works on 64-bit and your driver doesn't even get called on 32-bit, I'm guessing the issue is the size of `off_t` and the fact that 0x80000000 overflows 32 bits and becomes a huge negative number.

What if you put

```
  #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

as the first line of your userspace source code?  (Or pass "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" on the gcc command line)?

Comment: I'm doing pread/pwrite to the driver. Neither of those suggestions worked.

Comment: What does "pread/pwrite to the driver" mean?  What file are you accessing, and how did you create it?  What does strace show when you access offset 0x80000000 on 32 bits?

Comment: I'm accessing the device. I open the /dev/ entry for the device and call pread/pwrite with the returned file descriptor. This corresponds to the read/write functions in the device driver. strace shows `pwrite64(3, "\1\0\0\0"..., 4, 18446744071562067968) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)` when I call `pwrite(dev0, &i, 4, 0x80000000);` It looks like it's sign extending to 64-bits but I'm not sure why. I also don't know why it calls pwrite64 when I don't have either of your original suggestions being used.

Comment: Ok looks like I have to change the call to `pwrite64(dev0, &i, 4, 0x80000000ULL);` for it to work.